# Recursive select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have the following table entries:

```
 Col1    |    Col2
 ------------------
  3RDT   |  3R9H
  3R9H   |  
  3R9J   |  3RDT
  3R9J   |  3R9H
  3HHA   |  3ABC
  3XXZ   |  3HHA
```

I have a value `3R9J`.
Now I want all records where Col1 has that value, in this case record 3 and 4.

Now I take the Col2 values of this records (`3RDT` and `3R9H`) and consider those as my new Col1 values to get all records with the Col1 value `3RDT` or `3R9H`.

This should be done recursively. In addition it should also select all records in the other direction. If I start with `3RDT` for Col1 I get the records where Col2 is `3RDT` (3), then I have `3R9J` for Col1 and get all records where I have `3R9J` as Col1 value.

The expected output data in my example above should be the first 4 records.

Comment: Have you thought about trying to use a `JOIN`?

Comment: Please add the expected output based on your sample data. Also look at questions tagged with [connect-by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connect-by) or [recursive-query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query)

Comment: CONNECT BY is the best approach to solve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, that this query will do the job.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/337ba/1)

```
select *
  from test
  connect by col1 = prior col2
  start with col1 = '3R9J'
union
select *
  from test
  connect by prior col1 = col2
  start with col1 = '3RDT';
```

Please note that the `union` causes that each line is shown once.

Comment: If I omit the union I get double lines which is not what I want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yes, but please note that `connect by` have different conditions. It's possible to join them using `or `, adding `distinct` and `nocycle` to query, it worked for me, but I doubt it would be faster. Thanks for comment anyway.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that. Then of course it won't work.